# How to change DDMS icon on OSX

Tags: macos, android, osx-mavericks

I would like to change DDMS icon(Android Debug Monitor) on OSX Mavericks. It's appeared on Dock like below when to run it from Android Studio. And, It's not unremarkable because it's almost composed with colored white. 
Could you tell me about it?

[image: DDMS icon on Dock after run it from Android Studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default icon used for applications which don't supply their own.

As the file contains no icon, I don't think it can be changed.

Answer (score -1):

There is actually a way.

If you go to the Contents and find the [AppName].icns, you can edit this which will actually change the icon.

HOW TO DO IT:

1. Make an image or download one from the internet.
   To do it with an image you made: DO NOT SAVE IT. KEEP IT OPEN.
   To do it with a downloaded image: Save it as test and put it in the desktop.
2. Put the app in the Applications folder, if it is not already in there. Locate the app, right-click it, and click "Show Package Contents".
3. Go to Contents, then Resources, and locate [AppName].icns
4. Name the image the exact same thing.
   To do it with an image you made: Name it the exact same thing and save it to                 the desktop.
   To do it with a downloaded image: Rename the image to the exact same thing as the .icns file seen before.
5. Delete [AppName].icns from the APP (not the desktop) and drag the [AppName].icns (from the desktop) into the app.